# How to pass nested arrays from backend to frontend using Mongoose in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

This is my MongoDB schema:

```
var partnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    products: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        }]
});

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    campaign: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Campaign'
        }
    ]
});

var campaignSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
});


module.exports = {
    Partner: mongoose.model('Partner', partnerSchema),
    Product: mongoose.model('Product', productSchema),
    Campaign: mongoose.model('Campaign', campaignSchema)
}
```

And I'd like to send all documents (`partner`>`product`>`campaign`) to my View as a one object.

I know how to send `partner` with `product` ref. For example:

```
var campSchema = require('../model/camp-schema');
router.get('/partner-list', function (req, res) {
    campSchema.Partner.find({}, function (err, partnerList) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({ partnerList: partnerList });
    }).populate('products');
});
```

And I can easily iterate at view in this way:

```
   li(ng-repeat="product in partner.products")
       a(href="#") {{ product.name }}
```

And here is the question. How can I pass ONE object as a document with `partner`, `product` and `campaign`. Because at the moment I have only `partner` and `product` in that object.

Comment: Try this one : `.populate('products','products.campaign')` (probably would not work, but worth trying I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern to populate the nested campaign model:

```
var campSchema = require('../model/camp-schema');
router.get('/partner-list', function (req, res) {
    campSchema.Partner
        .find({})
        .populate({
            path: 'products',
            model: 'Product',
            populate: {
                path: 'campaign',
                model: 'Campaign'
            }
    }).exec(function(err, partnerList) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({ partnerList: partnerList });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't why but `.exec` doesn't work correctly. Error: `Expected ';'` http://prntscr.com/bk2aun Did I miss something?

Comment: @DiPix Apologies, I had left out the callback function. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you. Now I wondering how to remove object. If you can, then check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011068/how-to-remove-object-taking-into-account-references-in-mongoose-node-js