# How to get data from MongoDB to simple array using Node.JS and Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Let's say this is my MongoDB schema:

```
    var shopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        nameShop: String,
        products: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Product'
            }]
    });

    var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        nameProduct: String,
        fruits: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Fruit'
            }
        ]
    });

    var fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        nameFruit: String,
        price: Number
    });

module.exports = {
    Shop: mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema),
    Product: mongoose.model('Product', productSchema),
    Fruit: mongoose.model('Fruit', fruitSchema)
}
```

I know that I can get data in this way, but result of that code is an "ugly" array

```
var Schema = require('../model/schema');
    Schema.Shop.find({}).populate({
        path: 'products',
        model: 'Product',
        populate: {
            path: 'fruits',
            model: 'Fruit'
        }
    }).exec(callback);
```

Is it possible to get data from this schema in way that I will have nice array? E.g.:

```
var MyArray = [
                  { nameShop: "Tesco", nameProduct: "New", nameFruit: "Apple", price: 10 },
                  { nameShop: "Tesco", nameProduct: "New", nameFruit: "Pinapple", price: 4 },
                  { nameShop: "Eko", nameProduct: "Old", nameFruit: "Kiwi", price: 8 },
                  { nameShop: "Makro", nameProduct: "Fresh", nameFruit: "Pear", price: 7 },
                  { nameShop: "Carefour", nameProduct: "New", nameFruit: "Orange", price: 6 }
              ];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could go the aggregation framework route, which has the capacity to flatten the arrays through the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator. This will generate a new record for each and every element of the list data field on which unwind is applied. It basically flattens the data.

After flattening the data you would require the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator to do a "join" on the `products` field to the `products` collection. Repeat the process for the nested fruits schema.

Lets see an example (untested) to understand this better

```
var Schema = require('../model/schema');
Schema.Shop.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "products",
            "localField": "products",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "product"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$product" },
    { "$unwind": "$product.fruits" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "fruits",
            "localField": "product.fruits",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "fruits"
        }
    },  
    {
        "$project": {
            "nameShop": 1,
            "nameProduct": "$product.nameProduct",
            "nameFruit": "$fruits.nameFruit",
            "price": "$fruits.price",
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
})
```

**DISCLAIMER**: The above is untested code which only serves as a guide by making a couple of assumptions that you are running the code in a test environment with the latest MongoDB and mongoose versions that support the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator AND that you can perform the same aggregation query in mongo shell.

Comment: Result is Empty Array, anyway I'll try to fix this :)

Comment: This is result: http://prnt.sc/bmhft4 Inside is array with fruits I think you have misunderstood me. This is what I expected:  http://prnt.sc/bmhnpg Is it even possible?

Comment: Any idea or should I find another solution because in that way it's impossible to get it?

Comment: So maybe should I create this array using foreach on my current "ugly" array?

Comment: Because in your example I can get only first `Fruit` from each `Product`