# Deleting an element from an Object in MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, controller

I am trying to remove a `card` from the user's current project.
Each card follows the `CardSchema`.

I'm building a kanban board - this might be useful to know.

However, I've been unable to delete a card.

The structure of my database for this is as follows:

```js
"cards": [
    {
        "pending": {
            "cardIDHere": {
                // stuff here
            }
        },
        "inprogress": {},
        "completed": {}
    }
]

// or

project
    | - cards [Array]
        | - 0 [Object]
            | - pending [Object]
                | - cardIDHere [Object]
            | - inprogress [Object]
            | - completed [Object]
```

In other words, to get to a card you need:
`cards.0.<panel-name>.<card-id>`.

`panel-name` is the parent of the card: `pending`, etc.

My code:

```js
exports.updateCardPlace = async(req, res, next) => {
    const parent = await Card.findOne({"id":req.body.id});
    const path = `cards.0.${parent.panel}`;

    try{
        await Card.findOneAndDelete({"id": req.body.id});
        res.status(204).json({
            status: "Success"
        })
    } catch(err){
        res.status(300).json({
            status: "Error",
            message: err.message
        })
    }
}
```

Please note, `req.body.id` is the correct value, and `parent.panel` is valid.

However, I test this once - POST request comes back with code `204`. Ok, great. However, my error alert is shown.

So, I reload - maybe it's been deleted, as it should have been.

Nope, still there. Let's try deleting the card again.

Ah - an error this time:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'panel' of null
    at exports.updateCardPlace
```

I have absolutely no idea what this is about - could anyone help me?

**Card Schema**:

```js
const cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    summary: String,
    description: String,
    tags: Array,
    urgency: String,
    id: String,
    panel: String
});
```

**Project Schema**:

```js
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Project name is required']
    },
    type: String,
    photo: String,
    members: [String],
    code: String,
    cards: [{
        "pending": { 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object,
            ref: 'Card'
        },
        "inprogress": { 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object,
            ref: 'Card'
        },
        "issues": { 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object,
            ref: 'Card'
        },
        "completed": { 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object,
            ref: 'Card'
        }
    }],
    tags: Object
});
```

Comment: Can you include the schema for `Card`?

Comment: Sure. Adding now

Comment: Is the `cardSchema` nested in a different model, maybe `Project`? I'm a bit confused about where the path `cards.0.<panel-name>.<card-id>` comes in.

Comment: It is. Take a look now.

Comment: Ok. As for your desired output, what would the `cards` array look like afterwards? Should it remove the entire element from the array, or the `panel` field of the matching card?

Comment: It would remove the element in `cards[0][panel-name]` with the field name of `cardID`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226461/discussion-between-matt-and-montgomery-watts).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try something like this:

```js
const parent = await Card.findOne({"id":req.body.id});

try {
    await Card.findOneAndDelete({"id": req.body.id});
    await Project.updateOne(
        { `cards.${parent.panel}.${req.body.id}`: { $exists: true } },
        { $unset: { `cards.$.${parent.panel}.${req.body.id}`: "" }});
    res.status(204).json({
        status: "Success"
    })
} catch(err){
    res.status(300).json({
        status: "Error",
        message: err.message
    })
}
```

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011068/how-to-remove-object-taking-into-account-references-in-mongoose-node-js), it looks like you need to remove the reference on the `Project` model as well.

For my filter, I use `` { `cards.${parent.panel}.${req.body.id}`: { $exists: true } }} ``. I didn't specify the index `0` because I'm assuming there may be more than one element in the `cards` array. In the `update` document, I use the positional operator [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) to unset the `<panel-name>.<card-id>` field of the matching element in the `cards` array.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps what you want is ...

```
const parent = await Card.findOne({"_id":req.body.id});
```

mind the underscore in id (**'_id'**)

Comment: Hi, `id` is a separate field.