# mongoose, how to delete field not populated/returned null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to google search on how can I do this, but I'm not so sure the term I need to search for. I also thought I could just do a separate delete operation after the the find query, iterate through the array find the null ones(productId cannot be referenced since non existing) and delete them from the cart but I think there's more efficient way or chain commands to do this.

Basically what I wanted to do is whenever a field returned null or not found by populate, I'd like to remove that field and return only those fields that still exist. I just discovered about this when I started deleting certain documents that are referenced to other collections and errors showed up when reaccessing the cart.

So here is my query for basically retrieving cart items(with reference to Products collection via ID). By the way User collection contains the cartItems array, with the productsId.

```
User.findById(userId)

    .populate('cartItems._id')
    .then(result=>{

        return result.cartItems; //some items will be null since the reference id is non existing anymore in Products collection


    }).catch(error=>{

        return error;
    })
```

Thank you. I hope someone can help me with this matter.

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish but from what I understand this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011068/how-to-remove-object-taking-into-account-references-in-mongoose-node-js might help